# AngularJS simplistic directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to create a directive for bootstrap-select:

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ (it allows creating nice looking selects)

according to the following tutorial it should be an easy task to convert jquery plugin into angular directive: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Bu73oQQSio
But in fact it isn't at current point I'm stuck on my first step, I'm unable to get the most basic functionality working. I've tried different approaches:

```
<select multiple selectpicker>
  <option selectpickeroption ng-repeat="MyModel in MyModels">
    {{ MyModel.MyProperty }}
  </option>
</select>

<selectpicker multiple="multiple">
    <option ng-repeat="MyModel in MyModels">
        {{ MyModel.MyProperty }}
    </option>
</selectpicker>
```

together with

```
Application.directive('selectpicker', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function() {
            return function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
                element.selectpicker(); // launch `.selectpicker()` plugin
                // Lunching selectpicker at current point is way to early,
                // at this point all <option ng-repeat="MyModel in MyModels">..</option>
                // contain the following text `{{ MyModel.MyProperty }}`
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

But none of them worked, It just don't want to integrate into Angular. Is there a simple way of wrapping this simplistic plugin into angular with minimal effort? Because I've spent half day trying to make it work

:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue of timing - your `selectpicker` directive is running before the `<option>` elements have been created.

To get around this you need to delay your call to `element.selectpicker()` until the `<option>` elements have been created.

**Response to comments:**

@Lu4 #1: You're right, generally in Angular it's possible to avoid using `$timeout`.
I've updated the answer to use `$watch` instead (if you're using Angular 1.2+ then you'll probably want to use `$watchCollection`).

@dluz #2: As far as I'm aware the `$timeout` is reliable enough for this situation, however the updated answer should address any concerns about that.

Using `document.ready()` isn't appropriate here because that relates to the browser's state of the loaded page, not how Angular works with the DOM.  Because our Angular code is already running know that the ready event has already fired - `document.ready()` has to fire before Angular can run.

The issue that Lu4 has encountered is to do with how Angular processes directives - it operates on each element from the outside in, initialising all directives before moving onto the child elements and their directives (for simplicity we're ignoring `terminal` directives). So when the `selectpicker` directive is invoked Angular hasn't processed the child elements yet.

### Updated Answer:

Update your HTML to pass `MyModels` into the selectpicker directive as the collection you want to watch.

```
<select multiple selectpicker="MyModels">
    ...
</select>
```

Then update the directive to set up a `$watch` on the value of the `selectpicker` attribute.

From my quick tests the `$watch` will fire once the DOM has been updated and you should be able to call `selectpicker()`.

```
myApp.directive('selectpicker', [
    return {
        function(){
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, iAttrs, controller){
                console.log('selectpicker::link: element=', element.eq(0).children().length);
                
                scope.$watchCollection(iAttrs['selectpicker'], function(newValue){
                    console.log('selectpicker::$watch: element=',  element.eq(0).children().length);
                    element.selectpicker();
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

With this approach the `$watch` will fire when the collection is set on the scope or if the collection is replaced. In Angular 1.2 you should use `$watchCollection` so you can be notified if the number of items in the array change.

---

### Orignal Answer:

To get around this you need to use the `$timeout` service to delay your call to `element.selectpicker()` until the next "tick".

```
myApp.directive('selectpicker', ['$timeout',
    function($timeout){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, iAttrs, controller){
                // Log the number of children of the <select>.
                // This will be 0 because Angular hasn't processed the children yet.
                console.log('selectpicker::link: element=', element.eq(0).children().length);
                
                var initSelectpicker = function(){
                    // Now the children have been created.
                    console.log('selectpicker::init: element=', element.eq(0).children().length);
                    
                    element.selectpicker();
                }
                
                $timeout(initSelectpicker, 0, false);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

That should get things started but you're going to have to be careful - if `MyModels` changes then you're going to have to make sure that the selectpicker is kept up to date as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about using timeouts but had no internal motivation for such approach, thought that there might be some "correct" way around, is that a common practice to use a timeout for such purpose?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Sly_cardinal. You're correct. About the `$timeout` solution, do you think it's reliable?! I am not a big fan of relying on delayed events by timeout. Wouldn't be possible to only fire the `element.selectpicker();` inside a `document.ready()` method or something like this to make sure it's only fired when the DOM is ready ?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the plugin using the `link:` function of the directive. You only will be able to register any listeners on the elements and set up any watches with the scope during the link phase. (not the compile phase)

If you take a closer look at the YouTube video tutorial you mentioned, he is doing everything inside the `link:` function.

```
 myApp.directive('selectpicker', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, iAttrs, controller) { 

              console.log(element);
              element.selectpicker(); 

            }

        };
    }]);
```

As a rule you will only need to use the `compile` phase if you need to transform/change the template's DOM element. In the other hand the `link` function will allow the directive to register listeners on the specific cloned DOM element instance as well as to copy content into the DOM from the scope.

You can find out more here - http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Actually, what you've written is equivalent to what Lu4 has written. In the directive documentation you linked "Compile function" section: "A compile function can have a return value which can be either a function or an object. Returning a (post-link) function is equivalent to registering the linking function via the 'link' property of the config object..."

Comment: Thank you dluz, Sly_cardinal, yeah these declarations are equivalent, `link: function(...){...}` is just a shortcut